# How do I get Azure DevOps Workitem using postman

Tags: azure-devops, postman, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to figure out how I can use postman to access a workitem API, I found this part:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?api-version=5.1
```

I substituted the organization and project for my devops ones and gave it a random workitem id (within my workitems).

Then I put bearer token for authentication and I put my tenant ID.

I was watching videos saying I need client ID, client secret, etc... But I am using a free trial and have no access to some of that information. Upon asking my college, I was told I only need the URL and tenant id.

When doing all of that I get status 203 non-authoritative information.

What else am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the tenant ID, you need [a personal access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page), you choose **Basic** for Authorization type and:

Username: leave blank

Password: {Your Personal Access Token}

Comment: I did that and get: 401 unauthorized